# How can I implement a container with a controllable frame buffer in java?

Tags: java, performance, rendering

I am working with a game and i want to make game-play recordable and live-stream-able. The APIs i am working with are written in c++ so my project is cut in half. the two halves run simultaneously and share some memory (shared with memory-mapped files) for communications. The java half is the game and the c++ half is encoding.

I want the java half (game half) to send rendered frames to the c++ half (encoding half) through the shared memory.

**How can i implement a container, in java, that uses a section of the shared memory as a frame-buffer, without copying the frames?**

I want the frame buffer to be in the shared memory so the game doesn't need to copy every frame and create more work than it needs to do already.

Comment: *"works entirely in applet"*  Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: i didn't make it, i am just making the launcher for it, if you want to know what game, which can give you an idea of how much there is for me to make my launcher do, including modding the game for the user, it's Minecraft.

Comment: *"i am just making the launcher for it, .. Minecraft."*  To launch it I would recommend [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  OTOH I cannot tell what your actual question is.  (There is something to be said for adding an explicit '?' in the text of a question)

Comment: there's a lot more to the applet than you think, there is a launcher that comes for it and users aren't supposed to be able to tell it's an applet, the launcher is in charge of a bunch of things login related. I am making this one because the original one sucks and i am adding features to mine. Anyway, i didn't include all of what i am saying now because it's not important, this same question can apply if it wasn't an applet, the question here is: "How i can implement a container and specify the frame buffer so another project sharing a section of memory can do encoding to the frames?"

Comment: I guess if I'm being unclear here I'll overwrite the question and be more to the point. I included all the junky details for people to have in mind what i expect the solution to fit, but i guess i just made it a problem.

Comment: There you go, Andrew, short and to the point...